# Probability a football team wins with three probabilities given

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A football team has a $75$% chance of victory per game, if their captain is in good form.
If the captain is in bad form, their chance of victory is $40$%.
In $70$% of the games, the captain is in good form.

I want to calculate the probability of the following:

- (a) the team wins a game
- (b) the captain is in good form, but the team doesn't win a game

Regarding (a), I think

$$ (0.75 \cdot 0.7) = 0.525 $$

Regarding (b), I think

$$ (0.7 \cdot 0.75) \cdot 0.4 = 0.21$$

Is this correct or wrong?

Comment: It's wrong.  I can't follow your reasoning at all.  Why would you multiply $.75$ by $.4$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this is wrong.
Let "Captain in good form"=$C$

For part 1:
$$P(Win)=1-P(Loss)$$
$$P(Loss)=P(Loss\cap C)+P(Loss\cap C')=P(Loss/C).P(C)+P(Loss/C').P(C')=0.25×0.7+0.6×0.3=0.355$$
Hence $P(Win)=0.645$

For part 2:

$$P(Loss/C).P(C)=P(Loss\cap C)$$
Hence $P(C\cap Loss)=0.25×0.7=0.175$

Comment: How could the probability of a win be less than $.4$?  After, in the worst case (wherein the captain is playing poorly) ,the probability of a win is $.4$

Comment: Kindly check it now

Comment: The first is correct, by why bother computing the Loss probability?  That just adds a step for no gain. I don't understand what you wrote for the second part. The answer to that one is (clearly) just $.25$

Comment: No, we know the probability of Loss given that Captain is in good form. We don't know the probability of Captain being in good form, given loss.

Comment: And no one asked about that.  The problem requests the probability of a loss, conditioned on the captain playing badly.  "but" just means "and".

Comment: Even in such a  case it won't be 0.25...rather it would be 0.25×0.7

Comment: Sure, you could defend that answer  But not the Bayes' Theorem interpretation.